# Ajax request from checkout page js file to controller

Tags: magento2, checkout, ajax, jquery

I want to make Ajax request to the controller from checkout page. The code I have in [github](https://github.com/user3748173/Magento2_customShipping) and in my previous [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142119/jquery-ajax-data-to-controller?noredirect=1#comment193667_142119) were I did not specify that **I want to make the ajax request from js file placed on checkout page.** The current ajax request is displaying an error in console: `jquery.js:9666 POST https://127.0.0.1:8443/checkout/vendor_checkoutshipping/index/htmlcreator 404 (Not Found).` Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong that the ajax request is not made?

**I prefer not to use phtml file, unless I really need to (the reason for using would possible  security threth).** *(My module currently does not need phtml file.)*

Comment: Do you have a route defined for your controller? The URL that you have for the Ajax call suggests that you are missing that piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I can not understand what you mean by "having route defined for your controller"? You can see yourself what files i have in github. I suspect that the problem is that i can't use jQuery `url: 'vendor_checkoutshipping/index/htmlcreator'` in js file? Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax request url should not have 'index' in it. The url should be `vendor_checkoutshipping/htmlcreator`. Placing a controller in the `Controller/Index` folder and/or naming it `Index.php` means that the word 'index' is not included in the url path.

Comment: I tried it, but still getting 404 error. (The url in console does not contain index anymore).

Comment: Also, the URL should not have 'checkout' in it.

Comment: How can i remove it? Magento adds the 'checkout' to the URL. [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142119/jquery-ajax-data-to-controller?noredirect=1#comment193667_142119)

Comment: You put a slash at the start so that it is based off the root: `/controller/action` instead of `controller/action`.