# Can't get ajax request post in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, controllers, ajax

In my js file i have this ajax request :

```
var url = $(this).closest("form").attr('action');
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                     data: {
                    "key": "test1",
                    "key2": "test2"
                },
                dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (msg) {
                    //alert("success");
                });
```

In my controller i have this code:

```
 public function execute()
    {

         $response = [
            'errors' => false,
            'message' => 'Re-calculate successful.'
        ];
        $returnValue = '2';
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $escaper = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper');

        $id= $this->getRequest()->getPost('key2');

        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            $returnValue = 'OK';


        }

        return $result->setData($returnValue);
    }
```

When i make the ajax request i receive **2** which came from here `$returnValue = '2';`

But if i tired to get the `$id= $this->getRequest()->getPost('key2');` i receive null.

so my problem is here:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
   $returnValue = 'OK';     
 }
```

My if is not accessed.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Check Below Links, they will help you,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142119/jquery-ajax-data-to-controller
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911862/check-if-request-was-sent-by-ajax-or-not